# Htaccess 301 redirect with dynamic URLs

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect my dynamic URLs with parameters to subfolder URLs.
The source URL can vary in length/levels.

An example would be:

**Source:**

```
http://www.example.com/dir/?lang=en
```

**Desired:**

```
http://www.example.com/dir/en
```

and another would be:

**Source:**

```
http://www.example.com/dir/subdir/?lang=en
```

**Desired:**

```
http://www.example.com/dir/subdir/en
```

I'm using WordPress, so there is some existing code in my `.htaccess`, which the redirect in question, needs to work with. My existing `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I tried searching the entire web, however, no solution/answer seems to fit this particular case.
Any experts who can help?

Comment: Is this problem solved mixing the code as @anubhava proposed? If not I believe you should get a quick check to htaccess rewrite commands [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#rewrite) or [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html), and if you achieve a solution by yourself you can post your own answer, but if not, let us know with a comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?lang=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I can't figrure it out. I have the following code in my .htaccess file (from wordpress). 


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Does your suggestion work together with this? And if so, how? Thank you very much.

Comment: Anyone who can answer?

Comment: You need to explain your problem in hand first. Like is my suggested answer working or not? If not then what didn't work. Lastly you should not provide code comments in comments. Edit your question and copy/paste your .htaccess there.